# Problema con los Frame dentro de Frame, tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy empezando con tkinter, quisiera poner un frame como base y otro en el medio del primero, (fragmento):

```
frame = tk.Frame(raiz, width = "400", height = "400")
frame.pack()

frame_2 = tk.Frame(frame)
frame_2.pack()
frame_2.config(width = "260", height= "230", bg = "grey")
frame_2.config(bd = 15, relief = "flat")
```

Al ejecutar sale solamente el segundo frame, aclaro que no indique raiz.geometry.
Gracias por leer, saludos

Comment: Hola Luxio, en la respuesta a la pregunta marcada como duplicada se explica porqué pasa ésto y cómo solucionarlo. En tu caso: `frame.pack_propagate(0)` basta. Si queres centrar el segundo frame usa expand: `frame_2.pack(expand=True)`. Si tienes cualquier duda, comenta. Un saludo y bienvenido a [es.so]